# virt-sysprep libguestfs read-only filesystem error when cloning VM

Tags: virtual-machine, qemu, kvm, libvirt

I am trying to follow [this guide](https://dev.to/mediocredevops/cloning-kvm-snapshots-1paj) to clone a qemu VM.  However, when I try to run virt-sysprep on the image it gives me this error:

```
virt-sysprep: error: libguestfs error: rm_f: 
/$Recycle.Bin/S-1-5-21-1688936165-2161855017-2383321008-1001/$IH4CGML.bak: 
Read-only file system

If reporting bugs, run virt-sysprep with debugging enabled and include the 
complete output:

virt-sysprep -v -x [...]
```

Anyone know how to resolve this?  I'm hoping the solution doesn't involve modifying files individual snapshots, as the VM in question has a large number of them.